# case in select sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a problem with an sql statement, I have to average 5 notes but as long as the fields are full, I have the fields f1, f2, f3, f4 and if f1 and f3 are full my select must add f1  and f3 and divide it by Two but if f1, f2 and f4 are full you must add it and divide it by 3, I've tried CASE but it does not work, it just always leaves a case.

This is my code:

```
SELECT b.nombreAlumno As 'Alumno', f1 as 'F1' ,f2 as 'F2',f3 as 'F3',f4 as 'F4',sumativa as 'Sumativa',
'Promedio' =  Case 
when f1 > 0 then @promedio=(f1 + sumativa) / 2 
when f2 > 0 then (f1 + f2 + sumativa) / 3
when f3 > 0 then (f1 + f2 + f3 + sumativa) / 4
when f4 > 0 then (f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + sumativa) / 5
End

FROM tbNotas a,tbalumnos b
WHERE   idquimestre=@quimestre and idParcial=@parcial and idmateria=@materia and a.idalumno=b.idalumno and a.idparalelo=@paralelo
and a.idcurso=@idcurso
```

My Data
f1 10
f2 8.67
f3 10
f4 0
sumativa 1

Results 5.5 ( that's bad because would should add 10 + 8.67 + 10 + 1 / 4 => 7.4)

thanks for your help.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sql Server i use

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value is 0 or NULL when you want to ignore them, you can just do:

```
select ( (coalesce(f1, 0) + coalesce(f2, 0) + coalesce(f3, 0) + coalesce(f4, 0) + coalesce(f5, 0)) * 1.0 /
         ( coalesce(f1 > 0, 0) + coalesce(f2 > 0, 0) + coalesce(f3 > 0, 0) + coalesce(f4 > 0, 0) + coalesce(f5 > 0, 0) )
       ) as average
```

If the value only takes on `0` and not `NULL`, the `coalesce()`s are not needed.

EDIT:

The above is for MySQL.  A more general solution is:

```
select ( ((case when f1 > 0 then f1 else 0 end) +
          (case when f2 > 0 then f2 else 0 end) +
          (case when f3 > 0 then f3 else 0 end) +
          (case when f4 > 0 then f4 else 0 end) +
          (case when f5 > 0 then f5 else 0 end)
         ) /
         nullif( (case when f1 > 0 then 1.0 else 0 end) +
                 (case when f2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
                 (case when f3 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
                 (case when f4 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
                 (case when f5 > 0 then 1 else 0 end), 0
               )
         )
```

Comment: great!!! works so fine in sql server, but i have to show 2 decimals and i put cast ( as decimal (5,2)) as prom and dowsn work?? do you know why? thaks a lot.,

Comment: Right now is performing integer division. Try multiply your numerator for 1.0 to make it float `1.0 * (( CASE ....`